# How to find string between '\begin{minipage}' and '\end{minipage}' by python re?

Tags: python, regex

I have tried the following code:

```
strReFindString = u"\\begin{minipage}"+"(.*?)"
strReFindString += u"\\end{minipage}"
lst = re.findall(strReFindString, strBuffer, re.DOTALL)
```

But it always returns empty list.

How can I do?
Thanks all.

Comment: Try using raw strings (e.g., `ur"\\begin{minipage}"+"(.*?)"`)

Answer (score 2):

As @BrenBarn said, `u"\\b"` parses as `\b`; and `\b` is not a valid regexp escape, so `findall` treats it as `b` (literal b). `u"\\\\b"` is `\\b`, which regexp understands as `\b` (literal backslash, literal b). You can prevent escape-parsing in the string using raw strings, `ur"\\b"` is equal to `u"\\\\b"`:

```
ur"\\b" == u"\\\\b"
# => True
```